# Get all opened files in folder

Tags: objective-c, macos, lsof

I know that there is util **lsof**  which I can use to get a list of all opened files in specified directory.

But I want to get such info from my osx app. Can't find any lsof-like function which I can use. Any osx API that can do the same as it does **lsof** ?

main lsof doesn't shows any headed file which I can include to my app.

I can run **lsof** via **NSTask** but it doesn't feels like the right way.

Thanks

Comment: Why wouldn't it "feel like the right way"? `NSTask` is meant for that and `lsof` should work fine.

Comment: Just wondering, isn't there any API that wraps lsof ?